# Project rendering onto a polygon in the scene

Tags: opengl, matrix, projection

I have a function that renders a simple OpenGL scene. I want to display this scene on a polygon within another scene, without the function having to know about it. For example, to display the scene on the red polygon indicated:

[image]

I can set up the projection and modelview matrices to render to a small rectangle on the screen, but that doesn't work in a case like the image shown, where the target polygon is transformed and is no longer a rectangle on the screen. Is it possible to render to a non-rectangular target like this? The target is defined by four vertices, and I'm just not sure how to put those into the matrices.

I am aware of VBO/FBO functions that can render the sub-scene to a texture, which could then be mapped onto the polygon. However, this would be a bit more work as I'd have to add support for these functions to LuaGL, and I get the feeling it'd be slower than simply altering the display matrices - if it can even be done that way.

Comment: I think, that when you want to have general solution, you will have to use FBOs. In OpenGL it's not as hard, as it looks.

Comment: Do you want the inner scene to be *clipped* by the red polygon, as if it were a window into the inner scene, or should the image of the inner scene be *distorted* so that its four corners always match up with those of the polygon, no matter what its shape?

Comment: The latter. I want the polygon to show the entire scene.

Comment: I've just written the world's longest answer, and then read these comments and realised that I'd misunderstood the question.  Oops!

Comment: Probably this thread can help you? http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/174072-Render-to-texture-without-FBO

Comment: I'd edit the question and add [tag:luagl]. In normal OpenGL FBOs are the only sensible solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [stencil buffer](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Stencil_buffer) to clip an arbitrary shape out.  However, *you still need to compute the orientation of that red polygon*, and figure out what pixels it occupies, so you still have to use an FBO in order to get that stencil buffer each frame.

1) Render the small red polygon (to an FBO still) and create a stencil buffer from the pixels it covered

2) Orient the camera as you like and render the scene with that stencil buffer you just created active

### Using an FBO (recommended, easier, more flexible, "standard" way to do this kind of thing)

The way you would do this is:

1) Create an [FBO](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) with a texture2D as a backing

2) Render the scene (to the texture)

3) Now render your scene to the screen FBO, and render the texture you just created to the polygon you want it to display on

This is how you get "mirrors" to appear in games too.

Comment: The only negative side of the FBO approach is resolution / aliasing. Rendering directly to the rectangle will stretch to whatever resolution and viewing angle, while FBO will be limited to the FBO resolution; some pixels will be rendered to the FBO and never shown on screen, others may be stretched to cover more than one pixel.. but overall, FBO is still the hands-down easiest method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use glReadPixels to read pixels from the frame buffer - [explanation page](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't LuaGL support any buffers? These can be normal renderbuffers, if FBO are unavailable. Anyway, adding hooks for these functions shouldn't be hard.

It can be done using proper matrix calculations, but it would be non-linear projection and would require really complex calculations. In every game it's simpler to just render to memory and then back on the screen; this also has the benefit of easy applying of post-effects.